# Android Scroll View not filling Device Screen

Tags: android, xml, fragment

Hello I have a fragment that loads an Xml file. The xml file code is given below.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical"
> android:scrollbars="vertical"
> android:background="#2f3799"
> android:fillViewport="true"
> tools:context=".NewItem"
> android:paddingEnd="0dp"
> android:paddingStart="0dp">
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="#111a42"
>         android:weightSum="1">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="60dp"
>             android:text="SUBMIT YOUR POST"
>             android:id="@+id/textHeading"
>             android:textSize="15pt"
>             android:textColor="#ffffff"
>             android:textAlignment="center"
>             android:layout_weight="20" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>         android:text="Category"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/textCategory"
>         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
>     <GridLayout
>         android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>         <RadioGroup
>             android:id="@+id/categoryRadio"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="horizontal" >
>             <RadioButton
>                 android:id="@+id/motoRadio"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:checked="true"
>                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
>                 android:text="Motorbike" />
>             <RadioButton
>                 android:id="@+id/carRadio"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:checked="true"
>                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
>                 android:text="Car" />
>             <RadioButton
>                 android:id="@+id/otherRadio"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:checked="true"
>                 android:text="Others"
>                 android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
>         </RadioGroup>
>     </GridLayout>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>         android:text="Title"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/textTitle" />
>     <EditText
>         android:layout_width="300dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
>         android:id="@+id/titleText"
>         android:inputType="text"
>         android:hint="Item Title"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:visibility="visible"
>         android:typeface="sans"
>         android:layout_weight="0.65"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:layout_gravity="left"
>         android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"/>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>         android:text="Subject"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/textSubject" />
>     <EditText
>         android:layout_width="300dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:inputType="text"
>         android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
>         android:id="@+id/subjectText"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:visibility="visible"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:typeface="sans"
>         android:hint="Item Subject"
>         android:layout_weight="0.65"
>         android:layout_gravity="left" />
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>         android:text="Content"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/textContent"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/subjectText"/>
>     <EditText
>         android:layout_width="300dp"
>         android:layout_height="100dp"
>         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:id="@+id/contentText"
>         android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:textAlignment="textStart"
>         android:textColor="#232121"
>         android:layout_below="@id/textContent"/>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>         android:text="Source"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/textSource"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/contentText"/>
>     <EditText
>         android:layout_width="300dp"
>         android:layout_height="50dp"
>         android:inputType="text"
>         android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
>         android:id="@+id/sourceText"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/button"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/textSource"/>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="SUBMIT"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:id="@+id/button"
>         android:onClick="submitItem"
>         android:layout_gravity="center" />
> </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Even after setting the `android:fillViewport="true"`, the view does not fill the entire device screen. See the picture below for clarity. Awaiting your response. Thanks
[image: Android Emulator]

Comment: Whats showing behind it? can you post the layout with the fragment container?

Comment: Nothing is showing underneath its just blank with white color. The yellow marker is to buttress my point of the space.

Comment: Anyway post the layout xml with the fragment container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've the default paddings, check your activity layout and delete these lines:

```
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Thats why i asked for the activity layout.

Comment: @Nanoc I really wasn't sure of the layout you're talking of.

Answer (score 0):

change your dimens file

```
 <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

then in the layout

```
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all padding lines from your xml

Answer (score 0):

Your activity file contains Padding in main layout tag.